# scala array.product function in 2d array

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array

I have 2 d array:

```
val arr =Array(Array(2,1),Array(3,1),Array(4,1))
```

I should multiply all inner 1st elements and sum all inner 2nd elements to get as result:

```
Array(24,3)
```

I`m looking a way to use map there, something  like :

```
arr.map(a=>Array(a(1stElemnt).product , a(2ndElemnt).sum ))
```

Any suggestion
Regards.

Comment: If you are sure that your nested **Arrays** will always have two elements it would be better to have an array of **Tuples**. Even better, use a **List**, **Vector**, **ArrayaSeq** or any other real collection, instead of plain arrays. - Anyways, you can solve this using `foldLeft` instead.

Comment: There is no reason in using `map` here. `map` takes a collection and a function to apply to each element an return a new collection of the same size. Whereas, you actually want to reduce all the elements in the collection into a single element, that is what folding does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works but note that it is not safe, it throws exception if `arr` contains element/s that does not have exact 2 elements. You should add additional missing cases in pattern match as per your use case

```scala
val result = arr.fold(Array(1, 0)) {
  case (Array(x1, x2), Array(y1, y2)) => Array(x1 * y1, x2 + y2)
}
```

### Update

As @Luis suggested, if you make your original `Array[Array]` to `Array[Tuple]`, another implementation could look like this

```scala
val arr = Array((2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1))

val (prdArr, sumArr) = arr.unzip
val result           = (prdArr.product, sumArr.sum)

println(result) // (24, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, yes tuple fits betters there. This works (y) !